# What are the limits of the harmless sensory effect of the Prestidigitation spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cantrips, illusion

If I cast [*prestidigitation*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/prestidigitation) the first bullet point says:

> You create an instantaneous, harmless sensory effect, such as a shower of sparks, a puff of wind, faint musical notes, or an odd odor.

So, a harmless sensory effect, would include these: Touch, smell, taste, **sight** and hearing. How far I can use visual sensory effects?

Can I conjure a small rain cloud above a creature's head?

Also what is the difference between this and illusions?

I need to know the limit, because the spell doesn't say the size of the effect, or its limits. Sight is a harmless sensory effect, so what the limit of the spell?

Comment: Some related questions: "[How long does the 'instantaneous harmless sensory effect' of Prestidigitation last?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/76099)" and "[Prestidigitation and Druidcraft “harmless sensory effect?”](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49035)"

Comment: I've edited your question a bit, in an attempt to fix some of the grammar and phrasing. If you feel this wasn't correct, feel free to [edit] it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 10 ft from the caster

[*Presditigitation*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/prestidigitation) has a listed range of 10 ft and it says you

> create one of the following magical effects within range:

In its simplest readings, the effect is inside the range. Whether any specific effect is possible is entirely up to the DM (talk with them), but note that the sensory effect is instantaneous, so the rain cloud might not read properly to observers and for that (any many similar uses) you might be better off with [*minor illusion*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/minor-illusion) (or more potent illusion spells).